# Merging dataframes based on ranges that are defined by columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes. One has some probability brackets.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ProbabilityBrackets' : [0,0.50,0.75,1.0,0.75,0.90,1.0,0],\
'Group' : pd.Categorical(["test","test","test","test","train","train","train","train"]),'Destination' : pd.Categorical(["-","A","B","C","AA","BB","CC","-"])})

  Destination  Group  ProbabilityBrackets
0           -   test                 0.00
1           A   test                 0.50
2           B   test                 0.75
3           C   test                 1.00
4          AA  train                 0.75
5          BB  train                 0.90
6          CC  train                 1.00
7           -  train                 0.00
```

The other dataframe has some random numbers and the group column.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'randomnumbers' : [0.2,0.15,0.78,0.35],\
    'Group' : pd.Categorical(["test","train","test","train"])})

   Group  randomnumbers
0   test           0.20
1  train           0.15
2   test           0.78
3  train           0.35
```

Now, I need to merge the two dataframes together by both group and based on the probability brackets. Merging by group is trivial. The challenging requirement is merging by based on probabilitybrackets and random numbers. A random number in df2 should be mapped to the smallest probability bracket that is larger than itself. E.g., test 0.2 in df2 is mapped to test 0.5 in df1. test 0.78 in df2 is mapped to test 1.0 in df1.

I did it as follows, which works well and :

```
for group in ['test','train']:
    brackets=df1[df1['Group']==group].sort_values(by='ProbabilityBrackets')['ProbabilityBrackets'].unique()
    bracketlabels = brackets[1:] #remove the first element of the list. (e.g., remove 0 from (0,0.5,1))
    df2.loc[df2['Group']==group,'ProbabilityBrackets']=pd.cut(df2['randomnumbers'],brackets, labels=bracketlabels) #assign random numbers to the brackets so that we can easily merge them with df1


df3=df2.merge(df1,on=['Group','ProbabilityBrackets'],how='left')
```

It generates the following output, which is what I want but it is slower than I want because I have thousands of groups in my dataset. Is there a way to do it faster in a pythonic way?

```
   Group  randomnumbers  ProbabilityBrackets Destination
0   test           0.20                 0.50           A
1  train           0.15                 0.75          AA
2   test           0.78                 1.00           C
3  train           0.35                 0.75          AA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
# Step 1
df_m = df2.merge(df1, on="Group", how="outer")
# Step 2
df_m["diff"] = df_m["randomnumbers"] - df_m["ProbabilityBrackets"]
# Step 3
df_m_filtered = df_m[df_m["diff"] < 0].set_index(
                    ["Destination", "ProbabilityBrackets"])
# Step 4
df_desired = df_m_filtered.groupby(
                    ["Group", "randomnumbers"])["diff"].nlargest(1).reset_index()

    index   Group   randomnumbers   Destination ProbabilityBrackets diff
0   0       test    0.20             A           0.50              -0.30
1   1       test    0.78             C           1.00              -0.22
2   2       train   0.15             AA          0.75              -0.60
3   3       train   0.35             AA          0.75              -0.40
```

Explanation:

1. Begin with an outer merge
2. Calculate differences between `randomnumbers` and `ProbabilityBrackets`
3. Filter the results with condition `df_merged["diff"] < 0` as we are interested in finding those whose `randomnumbers` is smaller than `ProbabilityBrackets`
4. Groupby `["Group" and "randomnumbers"]` and find the one with the largest `diff` within each group.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I like this approach as we avoid for loops.

Comment: @G.Deg thank you for the comment. btw, I think the `sort` in step 1 is not necessary thus deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing “Group” for every element in df2 to every element in df1 is a lot of unnecessary string comparisons. You could instead try putting all the elements of df1 into a dictionary with Group as the key and having lists of (ProbabilityBrackets, Destination) tuples as the values. When inserting each element from df1, insert the tuple into the list maintaining the sort by ProbabilityBracket so that you don’t have to sort it again. Then you can retrieve the appropriate (ProbabilityBracket, Destination) for each element in df2 by looking in the dictionary by Group and performing a binary search on the list by ProbabilityBracket.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it. Taking some cues from @JasonR.

**Explanation:**
-  We create a dictionary of tuples (Destination, ProbablityBrackets). This is done to avoid multiple times looping on df1
-  Next, we check dictionary keys in df2 and assign the result based on given criteria.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# remove these rows
df1 = df1[df1['ProbabilityBrackets'] > 0]

df_dict = defaultdict(list)

# create a dictionary of tuples in list
for index, row in df1.iterrows():

    df_dict[row['Group']].append((row['Destination'],row['ProbabilityBrackets']))


## this calculates the output
for index, row in df2.iterrows():

    d = df_dict[row['Group']]
    randnum = row['randomnumbers']

    ## this checks the suitable probablity bracket
    low = 10000
    tuple_ix = 10000

    for ix, (i, j) in enumerate(d):
        sub = (j - randnum)
        if sub > 0 and sub < low:
            low = sub
            tuple_ix = ix

    combination = d[tuple_ix]

    df2.loc[index, 'ProbabilityBracket'] = combination[1]
    df2.loc[index, 'Destination'] = combination[0]

    Group   randomnumbers   ProbabilityBracket  Destination
0   test        0.20              0.50              A
1   train       0.15              0.75              AA
2   test        0.78              1.00              C
3   train       0.35              0.75              AA
```